# Make a Linked Scene local with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, scene

I have a scene linked from another file. It can be made Local by clicking this button:
[image]

How do I do this with python?
For Objects, you can use bpy.ops.object.make_local. There does not seem to be any equivalent for scenes that I can find in the API